# Can't install octave forges with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, snap, locale, octave

[Octave Forges](https://octave.sourceforge.io/) fails to install [octave](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/octave.1.html) from repositories on Ubuntu 19.04 using snap octave v5.1:

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 66 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 26 column 14
    pkg at line 407 column 31
```

I also tried installing the packages from downloaded images:

```
>> pkg install symbolic-2.8.0.tar.gz
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_TIME = "C",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "C",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
For information about changes from previous versions of the symbolic package, run 'news symbolic'.
```

my locale settings

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

**UPDATE**

the situation has improved mostly for the better I now use the flatpak app instead of the snap app and everything works fine ( except that I'm still unable to install packages from repositories )

anyway I still face this annoying little issue every time I load Symbolic

```
syms x
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
Python communication link active, SymPy v1.3.
```

Comment: Try this: `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Since you are using a snap, perhaps this is related? [Can not install Image acquisition package in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179187/can-not-install-image-acquisition-package-in-octave)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the situation has changed and quite improved for the better now I'm able to install image packages but I get this annoying issue every time I load Symbolic and use it 

syms x
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
Python communication link active, SymPy v1.3.

Comment: What does the command `locale -a` output?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson
`locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
ar_EG.utf8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_IT.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

I fixed the last issue by adding

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in the file

```
/etc/default/locale
```

now it works as it should

```
>> pkg load symbolic
>> syms s
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: Python communication link active, SymPy v1.3.
```

Comment: `/etc/default/locale` is a readonly file. In Ubuntu , if you run `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` followed by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, choosing en_US. Log out + log in again, this will have updated `/etc/default/locale` and everything else that's needed to make this work as it should.